# SELECT query on large table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to review / refactor an existing stored procedure that targets a table (10+ millons of rows). The stored procedure signature can not be changed easily and it looks like below.

The stored procedure takes two strings delimited by pipes and uses a SQL function (`SplitDelimitedVarChar`) to split the string into a temp table which is then used in the actual select. The number of strings in the *array* string ranges from 1 to thousands.

The `DateValue` and `TimeValue` columns contains `int` representations of the timestamp in the row.

My question is if any one has any ides if this is a good (best?) solution or if it could be done better. The main question is if it could be optimized for speed?

Since the table is only accessed through this stored procedure the index is a non clustered with the `WHERE` columns and includes all the `SELECT` columns.

Thanks for any suggestions or pointers.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spdata_Get_Ana]
@beginTime INT,
@endTime INT,
@subscribers VARCHAR(MAX),
@exchanges VARCHAR(MAX) = '1:',
@beginDateValue int, 
@endDateValue int,
@target int = 1
AS  
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #exch (Item Varchar(20) COLLATE database_default)
INSERT INTO #exch
SELECT Item FROM [SplitDelimitedVarChar] (@exchanges, '|') ORDER BY Item
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx ON #exch (Item)

CREATE TABLE #subs (Item Varchar(20) COLLATE database_default)
INSERT INTO #subs
SELECT Item FROM [SplitDelimitedVarChar] (@subscribers, '|') ORDER BY Item
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx ON #subs (Item)

SELECT 
   [Id]
  ,'' AS 'Name'
  ,[NameId]
  ,[Level]
  ,[Ne]
  ,[CallId]
  ,[Bg]
  ,[DateTime]
  ,[TimeStamp]
  ,[LogOwnerSnb]
  ,[TypeOfLog]
  ,[AbsenceCode]
  ,[AnswerTime]
  ,[CallForwardingReason]
  ,[CallForwardingToNumber]
  ,[CallTransferTime]
  ,[CallTransferReason]
  ,[SeizedSubscriberType]
  ,[SeizedSubscriberTime]
  ,[SeizedSubscriberNumber]
  ,[CalledSubscriberService]
  ,[InSubscriberType]
  ,[InSubscriberNumber]
  ,[CallDirection]
  ,[SubscriberService]
  ,[ClearingCause]
  ,[ClearingCauseTime]
  ,[OnHookTime]
  ,[OutAnswerSubType]
  ,[OutAnswerTime]
  ,[OutAnswerSubNum]
  ,[RingingStartedTime]
  ,[ReroutedToNumber]
  ,[InitiatedService]
  ,[B26]
FROM [dbo].[data_centrex_Ana] AS A
WHERE
    (A.[DateValue] BETWEEN @beginDateValue AND @endDateValue)
AND
    EXISTS(SELECT [Item] FROM #exch WHERE [Item] = A.[Level])
AND
    (A.[TimeValue] BETWEEN @beginTime AND @endTime)
AND
(
   (@target = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT [Item] FROM #subs WHERE [Item] = A.[LogOwnerSnb]))
   OR
   (@target = 2 AND EXISTS(SELECT [Item] FROM #subs WHERE [Item] = A.[Bg]))
)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Doubt there is any benefit to including the select columns in the index.
It just makes for a big index.

Try as a join

```
SELECT [Id]  
FROM [dbo].[data_centrex_Ana] AS A 
JOIN #exch   
 ON [Item] = A.[Level] 
JOIN #subs    
  ON (@target = 1 AND [Item] = A.[LogOwnerSnb])   
  OR (@target = 2 AND [Item] = A.[Bg]) 
WHERE
     (A.[DateValue] BETWEEN @beginDateValue AND @endDateValue) 
AND  (A.[TimeValue] BETWEEN @beginTime AND @endTime)
```